# How do I attach a UI View below the elementKindSectionHeader of a Collection View?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have created a Collection View and have made good use of the `UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader` by registering a Header class. See my code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()           
        setupCollectionViewLayout()
        setupCollectionView()
        setupMenuBar()
    }

    var headerView: HeaderView?

    fileprivate func setupCollectionViewLayout() {
        if let layout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.sectionInset = .init(top: padding, left: padding, bottom: padding, right: padding)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func setupCollectionView() {
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .white

        //For iPhone X's make sure it doesn't cover the swipe bar at bottom
        self.collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        self.collectionView.register(HeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)

        self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 60, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        self.collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 60, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
```

which gives me a nice Header like:
[image]

But now I want a menu bar **beneath** the header, but **above** the main section of the collection view. I have created a MenuBar with the correct dimensions but I can't think what to constrain it to? See my code below to add a Menu Bar currently:

```
let menuBar: MenuBar = {
    let mb = MenuBar()
    return mb
}()
fileprivate func setupMenuBar() {
    view.addSubview(menuBar)
    view.addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: menuBar)
    view.addConstraintWithFormat(format: "V:|-400-[v0(50)]|", views: menuBar)
}
```

..but this literally just pins the bar 400px down the entire view and does not move if you scroll up or down

[image]

Does anybody have an idea for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want this menu bar to move with the `UITableView` scrolling, it should be placed inside the header, below the "main header".

This approach abstraction is considering your header + menu bar as just one header.